# What's the most efficient way of structuring this database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am in the process of designing a form handling web service similiar to [wufoo](http://wufoo.com) and [formstack.com](http://formstack.com) that users signup to, create a form action which they would copy and paste into their form and my service will store that data in a database and redirect back to their thank you page.

I am going to be building it using `PHP` and `MySQL`. So far, I have the basic functionality figured out but where im becoming unstuck at an abstract level is how best to store the users data.

My first thought was to create a new table for every new form created which seems a bit silly and over the top.

Now im thinking, I create a generic `data` table with say 50 fields, named: `field1, field2, field3, field4` etc and that would store everybody's data and then link that table to another called `fieldnames` where the user can customise their 'dashboard' to look like they have named the fields.

I'm really not too sure how best to handle this.

Comment: create 50 fields to hold data, then sit back and wait for a user to come in requiring 51.... then 52... then 53...

Comment: yeah exactly. where do i stop? but creating a new table per user seems mental.

Comment: "normalize". a table of users. a table of fields (userid, fieldid, fieldname, fieldtype, fieldvalue). e.g. a 1-many relationship.

Comment: Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two tables for the forms and fields plus one for the answers:

```
form(id, title, user ...)
field(id, form_id, order, title, type ...)
answer(field_id, value, ...)
```

That way you don't limit your users to a certain number of fields.

Comment: ok, but then where would i store the form data that been submitted on the users website?

Comment: A third table for the answers (see my edit).

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense than what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this - it depends mostly on what you want to do with the data once it's been entered.

hsan's answer is commonly known as "entity-attribute-value" or EAV. It's flexible, can store lots of different types of data (and doesn't run out when you need more than 50 answers). If you are storing the data to re-construct another web page (e.g. to show the owner of the form), it works pretty well; if you want to create something "human-readable", e.g. a report, it's a bit more tricky. If you want to ask questions of the data, it can be tricky - imagine finding all answers to the question "how much do you earn" where the answer is "25000-35000" where the user also said their favourite colour is "red".

You can also store the data in an XML or JSON document. This makes the data harder to reason about in SQL, but makes it pretty straightforward to transform the data into a report or PDF.

Comment: Once the data is stored. I want the user (form owner) to be able to login to my service, and view all entires from the form as if it were one table. Then generate a report on that, number of submissions, time and dates of submissions etc etc.